# Probability that Y>X in a vector unable to be calculated from distribution function

Tags: probability, random-variables

I was trying to help a friend solve this question:

Given a probability density function for a random vector:

$$f(x,y) = \frac{3}{4}(y-x)^2 \ \ \ \ \ \text{where (x,y)}\in[0,1] \times[0,2]$$
$$0\ \ \ \  \text{everywhere else}$$

Find P(Y>X).

Here is my integral (which yielded the correct result):

$$  \int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{2} \frac{3}{4}(y-x)^2 \,dy\,dx = \frac{15}{16}$$

My question is, however, why doesn't the following way work:

The distribution function for the given probability density function is

$$F(x,y)=\frac{xy^3}{4}-\frac{3x^2y^2}{8}+\frac{x^3y}{4}$$

If I wanted to calculate P(Y<X), I would intuitively use this: F(1,x) because x can be any number from 0 to 1 and y can be any number from 0 to x. Therefore, if I wanted to calculate P(Y>X), which is an opposite event from P(Y<X), I would calculate it like this:
$$1-F(1,x)$$ However, this results in a function, not in a specific number. Where did my intuition go wrong?

Comment: Because $F(1,x)$ is $\mathsf P(Y<x)$ and not $\mathsf P(Y<X)$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to calculate this using the distribution function?

Comment: Not really. You can do it only by taking derivation of it to integrate.$$\mathsf P(Y<X)=\int_0^1\left.\dfrac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}\right\vert_{\langle x,y\rangle=\langle s,s\rangle}\,\mathrm ds$$... but since you are actually starting from the mixed double derivative...that's basically just taking two steps forward, one step back, then one step slightly to the left.$$\mathsf P(Y<X)=\int_0^1\int_0^s\left.\dfrac{\partial^2 F(x,y)}{\partial x~\partial y}\right\vert_{\langle x,y\rangle=\langle s,t\rangle}\,\mathrm d t\,\mathrm ds\\=\int_0^1\int_0^s f(s,t)\,\mathrm d t\,\mathrm d s~~~~$$